# Relatively positioned block element affects size of it's parent

Tags: html, css

The best way to describe the issue would be by posting a jsFiddle, so [here it is](http://jsfiddle.net/u5qyg/).

And a screenshot for reference:

[image: Reference screenshot]

I have to put a `div` containing something within a `td` element, which has some formatting and height. The `div` cannot disrupt the cell's height but itself is a little bigger than `line-height` within the cell, so the whole row's height rises. It can be seen as the difference in height between the upper and lower tables on the screenshot.

Positioning the `div` relatively and moving it upward doesn't help. My question is - is it possible to somehow position the `div` in the exact same place as in my example but without affecting the table row's height?

Absolute positioning works as expected but has some flaws - the contents of the table and other elements of my page can change and therefore maintaining the proper position of the `div` would require monitoring it's parent with JavaScript which wouldn't be a very practical solution.

Thanks everyone for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the effect you're looking for by wrapping the `div` inside the table cell with another `div` which is relatively positioned. Then change your `div` to be absolutely positioned.

For some reason, jsFiddle, isn't loading for me right now, so here's the code.

**HTML**

```
<table class="some-table">
    <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>
            Cell 2
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="checkbox-div">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox"/>
                    <label for="checkbox">Label</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>Cell 3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br/>
<br/>
<table class="some-table">
    <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
        <td>Cell 3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
.some-table td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 200px;
    font-size: 10px;
}

.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    width: 200px;
}

.checkbox-div {
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: absolute;
    top: -20px;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: No problem. It does make things a little messy, so you might consider a JS solution like the link @MrLister posted.

Answer (score 1):

Relative positioning has no effect on layout, *only* on the position of the thing you are positioning. That's how it works.

The good news is that you can give something an absolute position relative to the table cell it's in. If you use a trick. See http://css-tricks.com/absolutely-position-element-within-a-table-cell/

Answer (score 0):

There will be always difference in height in your case, because of cehck box is just higher than text , so it require a bit more space, this causes higher element

If you remove position: relative and padding, you will see, that checkbox is higher by 2-4 pixles

Comment: I am aware of it. The thing is - I would like to somehow remove the div from the original flow - just like absolute positioning - but keep it relative to it's parent in case of offset/position so it would not affect the height.